# what is the name of this OST of episode 14 of shingeki no kyoujin?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

The ost were on Eren's speech during the trial scene when he called them cowards and defended Mikasa. Some said it's " Call your name" but i would have the link of the music as it sounded, if possible, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soundtrack's name is "Call your name", like you already mentioned. There is one version with vocals (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFoc5XKkIIw) and one without (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsc9Y_lH9CQ).